# CMD script to find and replace a part of found line in file

Tags: cmd

I need to find all lines in myfile.txt containing word 'MyWord', and then replace a part of this string next way:

Original line:

```
 ...,31-01-2012,00,some_words_and_symbols_and_digits,MyWord,...
```

After replace:

```
 ...,31-01-2012,01,some_words_and_symbols_and_digits,MyWord,...
```

Please, help me to write this cmd script!

OK.. I have next code:

```
@echo off
set code=MyWord
set req=new request

FOR /F "usebackq delims=, tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9*" %%a in (MyFile.txt) do (

IF %%h==%code% (
    SET tempstr=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,60,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i
    ) ELSE (
    SET tempstr=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i
    ) 

IF %%a==%req% (
    SET echo %%a >> new.strings
    ) ELSE (
    echo %tempstr% >> new.strings
    )

)
@echo on
```

And I have in my file something like:

```
 new request
 ...,31-01-2012,01,some_words_and_symbols_and_digits,MyWord,...
 new request
 ...,30-11-2011,01,some_words_and_symbols_and_digits,OtherWords,...
```

But then I have error:

```
ELSE was unexpected at this time.
```

And If I'm trying simple next in the end

```
IF %%a==%req% SET tempstr=%%a
echo %tempstr% >> new.strings
```

Then I have only one last row instead of other else

Comment: I edited my answer in response to your edit. Next time please leave a comment as a notification as stackoverflow does not inform users about edits to questions they answered to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` command to filter the lines containing given text. As I see, the file is CSV. So you can use `for /f` to parse the lines found. Then you can `echo` all parsed files replacing the field you want.

This will replace all values in the 3rd column with "01"

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq delims=, tokens=1,2,3,4,<put as many as you need>" %%A in (`find "MyWord" myfile.txt`) do echo %%A,%%B,01,%%D,<as many %%letters as tokens>
```

If you want to replace the value only on some lines, you can use `if` command inside `for /f` loop.

==== EDIT

The problem is with the value of `req` variable. It contains a space, so after substitution your second if statement has the following form:

```
IF %%a==new request (
```

so if `%%a` is equal to `new` it will execute `request ( echo ...... )` and then ELSE is unexpected indeed. Enclose both `%%a` and `%req%` in quotation marks and the problem will disappear.

But I see also other problems. First, you have redundant `set` in your second if statement.
Second, you need to use delayed expansion of variables, or your `echo %tempstr%` won't work.

Your code after needed changes:

```
@Echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set code=MyWord
set req=new request

FOR /F "usebackq delims=, tokens=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9*" %%a in (MyFile.txt) do (

  IF %%h==%code% (
    SET tempstr=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,60,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i
  ) ELSE (
    SET tempstr=%%a,%%b,%%c,%%d,%%e,%%f,%%g,%%h,%%i
  ) 

  IF "%%a"=="%req%" (
    echo %%a >> new.strings
  ) ELSE (
    echo !tempstr! >> new.strings
  )
)

endlocal
```